# Mobile CSS - Navigation not appearing

Tags: iphone, css, mobile

I have been working on making my website mobile compatible. Whilst I have successfully managed to link the mobile CSS and my web CSS, my navigation elements will not display!!

I would be grateful if anyone had any ideas as to why it wont display.

My site is www.therisingsuntarporley.co.uk, I have put my mobile CSS below.

Thanks

```
html, body 
        {
            font-size: 30px sans-serif;
            background: #000;
            padding: 3px;
            color: #000;
            margin: 0;
        }

#body 
        {
            margin-right: 0;
            margin-left: 0;

        }

#middle {

    width: 90%;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin-top: 65px;
    border:3px solid #333;
    background-color:#FFFFF0;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 75px; /* must be same height as the footer */
    }


#middlecontent 
        {
            font: normal 1.4em sans-serif;
            padding: 0px;
        }

#cencontent 
        {
            font: normal 1.4em sans-serif;
            padding: 0px;
            text-align: center;
        }


#mobilenav 

{  
  margin-top: 25%;   
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size:2.4em;
  font-family:Verdana;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
 }

#mobilenav a 
{   
  display: block;  
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 2.5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}

#mobilenav a:hover 
{ 
  background: #C1C1C1;
  color:white;
}

#mobilenav #con a {
  border: none;
}

#logo
        {
            width:100%;
            height: auto;
        }
#footer 
{
    border-top: 3px solid #7CFC00;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    clear:both;     
/*text colour*/
    font: normal 0.7em "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-stretch:expanded;
    background: #000;
}

#aboutus, #goomap,  #myGallery, #mainimage, #navbar
        {
            display: none;
        }
```

Comment: Which media type are you declaring in your css media tag? are you loading this css at the end?

Comment: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/site.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="handheld, screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />' Sorry! ment to include it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've forgotten to add add the following code to #mobilenav:

```
display: block !important;
```

Should workd without the !important too, if you load the mobile CSS after your standard css

Answer (score 0):

The iphone does load all css with media=screen as if it was a normal browser.

Comment: how would i only target iphone? I have tried media="handheld, only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" but it wont display my menu? I have two menus - one for web browsers and one for mobile web. Im guessing as iphone only reads the 'screen' type that is why it is displaying. I have specified in my main site css not to display my mobile menu and in my mobile style sheet I have specified not to display the web navigation? Any ideas?!